# sessionStorage return null

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

Im trying to achieve this piece of code but in my console it says thing is null which is weird because when I look in the console, sessionStorage isn't empty...

```
$(".btn-alert").click(function(){
        var identifierOfSpan = $(this > "span").text();
        for(var prop in sessionStorage){
            var thing = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(prop))
            if(thing.id == identifierOfSpan){
                sessionStorage.removeItem(prop);                    
            }
        }
        $(this).closest(".voyages").remove();
        if(sessionStorage.length == 0){
            alert("Message!");
            location.href="reservation.html"

        }
    });
```

the button is supposed to delete the div and the sessionStorage item which looks like this
[image]

[image]

Html :

```
  <div class="voyages">
<button class="btn btn-alert btn-md mr-2" tabindex="-1">delete the flight</button>
<span>ID : 4224762</span>
<div class="infos">
    <img src="img/angleterre.jpg" alt="maroc">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><h5>Angleterre, Londres (LON)</h5></li>
            <li><h5>2 adulte(s)</h5></li>
            <li><h5> Aucun enfants </h5></li>
            <li><h5>Type : Couple</h5></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Options</h3>
<ul>
    <li>voiture : 0</li>
    <li>Hotel : 0 </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h3>Prix :3713$</h3>
```

Comment: Very likely due to console showing you the live object, not the object at the point it was logged

Comment: but it seems like an error doesn't it?  how can I fix this?

Comment: Not an error, just unintuitive implementation.

Comment: I really wouldn't use `for..in` with `sessionStorage`. If you want to iterate, use `key()` instead ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key#Examples

Comment: Also, what is this meant to evaluate to? `$(this > "span")`. That will probably always be `$(false)` which isn't going to get you very far

Comment: oh ok, I thought it was an error for a moment! Im trying to remove every element form sessionStorage with the same id to the span, but I don't know if this works, does it?

Comment: @Phil I want to target the span in the object which represents a div but I don't know how, I read somewhere that you could target children of things but I don't think it works...

Comment: Still can't work out what `$(this > "span").val()` is _supposed_ to be. Even if you were after a `<span>` that was a child of the button clicked, it won't have a _value_. `.val()` works with form elements like `<input>`, not `<span>`. What property of the `<span>` are you after?

Comment: ahh I get it, I used val instead of text() that maybe why

Comment: Ok, so the `<span>`  is **not** inside the button and the text content isn't **only** the `id`. You really should have added the HTML at the start

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML structure at all?

Comment: No it's a sample the thing is that im doing a for loop on the load of body that creates this div for the number of flights that I have so this is just an example of what it looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to...

1. Click on a button
2. Find the first sibling `<span>` element and parse a number out of its text content
3. Remove all `sessionStorage` items (JSON serialized objects) with matching `id` properties

For the ID, I highly recommend adding some data directly to the `<button>` to help you identify the right record. If you can, try something like

```
<button class="btn btn-alert btn-md mr-2" data-voyage="4224762"...
```

Try something like this

```js
$('.btn-alert').on('click', function() {
  const btn = $(this)
  const id = btn.data('voyage')
  // or, if you cannot add the "data-voyage" attribute
  const id = btn.next('span').text().match(/\d+$/)[0]

  // for index-based removal, start at the end and work backwards
  for (let i = sessionStorage.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let key = sessionStorage.key(i)
    let thing = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key))
    if (thing.id == id) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem(key)
    }
  }

  // and the rest of your code
  btn.closest(".voyages").remove();
  if(sessionStorage.length === 0) {
    alert("Message!");
    location.href = 'reservation.html'
  }
})
```

---

The problem with using a `for..in` loop on `sessionStorage` is that you not only get any item keys added but also

- `length`
- `key`
- `getItem`
- `setItem`
- `removeItem`
- `clear`

Comment: your code is great but there's some details that you didn't understand, im trying to delete a div on the click of a button and to delete the object in sessionStorage witch matches the span id so if the first one has an id of 2 it should delete the item in sessionStorage witch possess the id:2

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r I don't see how I've missed any of that. The part with _"and the rest of your code"_ is where you would remove the `<div>`

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r I've now included _the rest of your code_ in my answer. Hope that makes it clear

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r _"it didn't work"_ is too broad a phrase to work with. How **exactly** did it not work? What debugging have you done? Perhaps the text content of the `<span>` isn't exactly right. You may need to `trim` it for example (I'll update my answer). You could help by providing the relevant HTML in your question

Comment: I'll edit my code to add the html so you would understand what im trying to do

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r I've updated my answer to use `next()` instead of `find()`

Comment: Thanks a lot this is ***exactly*** what I needed!